# How to force hide .php extension with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi everyone this is my **.htaccess** file code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It works perfectly but can I force hide the .php extension, so even if I went to [www.example.com/foo.php](http://www.example.com/foo.php) I get redirected to [www.example.com/foo](http://www.example.com/foo)

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This matches against a request for a php file, and then redirects the browser to the same request but without the `.php` extension.